# Logout users upon login, based on caps/role?

Tags: plugin-development, login, user-roles, capabilities, logout

To reduce spam registrations, users are assigned the `pending` role until they're vetted (at which point they're assigned the `subscriber` role). The `pending` role has no capabilities. When `pending` users log in, I want to log them out immediately and direct them to a page with an explanation. First, I tried the following:

```
function logout_pending_users() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user() ;
    if ( ! $current_user->has_cap( 'read' ) ) {
        $url = 'https://example.com/pending/' ;
        wp_redirect( $url ) ;
        wp_logout() ;
        exit ;
    }
} add_action('wp_login', 'logout_pending_users') ;
```

Result: both `pending` and `subscriber` users are logged out. I tried inverting the order of `wp_redirect()` and `wp_logout()`:

```
        $url = 'https://example.com/pending/' ;
        wp_logout() ;
        wp_redirect( $url ) ;
        exit ;
```

Same result. Then I tried checking roles instead of caps (I know, you shouldn't...):

```
function logout_pending_users() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user() ;
    $role = $current_user->roles[0] ;
    if ( $role === 'pending' ) {
        $url = 'https://example.com/pending/' ;
        wp_redirect( $url ) ;
        wp_logout() ;
        exit ;
    }
} add_action('wp_login', 'logout_pending_users') ;
```

Again, same result. Next, I tried something based on an example on the WP Developer site:

```
function logout_pending_users() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user() ;
    if ( ! $current_user->has_cap( 'read' ) ) {
        wp_logout() ;
    }
} add_action('wp_login', 'logout_pending_users');

function redirect_pending_users() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user() ;
    if ( ! $current_user->has_cap( 'read' ) ) {
        $url = 'https://example.com/pending/' ;
        wp_redirect( $url ) ;
        exit;
} add_action( 'wp_logout()', 'redirect_pending_users');
```

Result: both `pending` and `subscriber` users are stuck at the login page, with URL:
https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fprofile.php&reauth=1

During each attempt, I verified that the `pending` role has no `read` capacity (or any capacity), and that the `subscriber` role does. I also verified that `$current_user->roles[0]` does, indeed, contain the correct role.

What am I missing? Is there another way? Thank you for any help!

Comment: See if the answer to this post helps you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329551/custom-user-role-not-working-as-expected 

You need to kinda flush the roles cache to make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not. But thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of "timing" issues you're running into here.

When you're calling `wp_get_current_user()` this isn't really available at the moment of logging in, so to capture the logging-in user, you have to use a slightly different approach.

The same is with logout, as it uses the same method of getting the current user.

In the solution below you're capturing the logging-in user directly from the wp_login hook, and then instead of calling `wp_logout()`, you're calling the actual functions that do the logging-out for you.  And, instead of adding multiple hooks, you're doing it all within the one hook: `wp_login`

There's also a sanity check to ensure the `$user` is actually an `\WP_User` object, or you'll get a fatal error on checking the capability.

```php
function logout_pending_users( $username, $user ) {
    
    if ( $user instanceof \WP_User && !$user->has_cap( 'read' ) ) {

        wp_destroy_current_session();
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
        
        wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/pending/' );
        
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'logout_pending_users', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Lots of great information here — and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Could you accept the answer, please?

Comment: FIrst-timer. Tried to accept it yesterday but couldn't find an 'Accept' button anywhere! Finally figured it out. Thank you again!